# Copy Export Symbols From Mac to Windows PE

Tags: ida, windows, powerpc

I have both a Mac and Windows version of the same library. However, while the Mac version has export symbols, the Windows version exports by ordinal. The Mac version uses the PPC architecture making it more difficult to reverse.

Is there any way to heuristically compare these subroutines and copy the export symbols from the Mac version to the Windows version so that I can view them within IDA Pro for the Windows version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Diaphora tool](https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) by Joxean Koret can match functions in binaries with different architectures using multiple algorithms.

You can also always do it manually: make one match using strings or magic numbers used, then follow cross-references to find more matches.